# Default Apache webroot different to what I expect; seems to be /var/www/html rather than /var/www

Tags: apache, linux, ubuntu

I have a new installation of Apache in Ubuntu 14.04.2

The /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file contains:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

With this setting, it would make sense to me if the webroot was /var/www/ but based on behaviour (when I try to access it through a browser) it seems to be /var/www/html/

Why does it use the html subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

The file 000-default.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ defines the /var/www/html/ folder as the webroot (this is enabled by default, as you can see in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ folder):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: BTW- If the OP is not too familiar with web security, they do not want to edit the directory specification- just use the /var/www/html/ as specified and all will work just fine.